# Check photos for geotagging and remove lat/long data

Tags: privacy, geolocation

I like to upload photos to various internet services, but I prefer not to share my geographic location.  I understand Facebook and other services strip out the geolocation data, but they still have the data.  I want to keep that data to myself and not share geolocation.

What are some tools that can find if geolocation data exists in a photo?

Is there a way I can manually strip this data from my photos?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have used [exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) for this kind of work. It basicly lets you review and edit any meta information in your pictures.

I used this to exploit a image service which echoed the geo details back at the user. I filled the images geo data with XSS and attacked other users viewing the picture.

Comment: +1, and I wish I could get another +1 for you pointing out an implementation / security flaw in displaying that information.

Answer (score 3):

The data you're looking for is called Exif data. There's a ton of information about reading, preserving, changing, or deleting it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exif.

Answer (score 3):

First install Imagemagick and then mogrify -strip *.jpg for a directory of images or specify a single image and strip it.

Answer (score 2):

As Karrax says, [exiftool](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) is perfect for stripping this information from images.

More broadly, you might be interested in [MAT](https://mat.boum.org/), the Metadata Anonymisation Toolkit, which allows you to view metadata that is stored in all sorts of files.  This includes not just location data stored in images, but all sorts of data that may be stored in pictures, music files, documents, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Another very quick and simple solution can be found here: http://www.geotagsecurity.com/what-is-geotag-security/